# Updating a Parent Record's field using Child's Record Data (Same Table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have a table whereby there is a Parent/Child relationship, where each of the children's `ExternalCategoryCode` column data needs to be concatenated into the parents `ExternalCategoryCode`.

Here is some example data that is corrupted, whereby the Parent record (Id=96) 
`ExternalCategoryCode` is **NULL**. The relationship is via the `ParentId` field:

```
Id |Name                          |ExternalCategoryCode|ParentId
---|------------------------------|--------------------|--------- 
96 | Health & Personal Development| NULL               | NULL
---|------------------------------|--------------------|---------
97 | Health                       | H1*;H2*            | 96
---|------------------------------|--------------------|---------
98 | Personal Development         | P1;P2;P3*          | 96
---|------------------------------|--------------------|---------
99 | Other Health                 | OH*                | 96
---|------------------------------|--------------------|---------
```

The data should look like this:

```
Id |Name                          |ExternalCategoryCode  |ParentId
---|------------------------------|----------------------|--------- 
96 | Health & Personal Development| H1*;H2*;P1;P2;P3*;OH*| NULL
---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
97 | Health                       | H1*;H2*              | 96
---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
98 | Personal Development         | P1;P2;P3*            | 96
---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
99 | Other Health                 | OH*                  | 96
---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
```

**EDITs:**

1. The descendant level can be any levels deep, but the deep children
   descendants need updating to the main Parent's
   `ExternalCategoryCode`. Take the last two records below (**Id=100**
   and **Id=101**) both link to a `ParentId` 97. Because **Id=97**
   `ParentId` **IS NOT NULL**, we should continue up the tree until we
   find a record with a `ParentId` of NULL (Top most Parent).
2. Another question was regarding can the upper most parent's `ExternalCategoryCode` contain duplicates? Example below shows M2* twice. This is fine, because our business logic class libraries filter out duplicates if it finds any.
3. If a record has a link in its `ParentId`(i.e. is a child) **but** has a NULL `ExternalCategoryCode`, these codes can be ignored.

   ```
   Id |Name                          |ExternalCategoryCode  |ParentId
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|--------- 
   96 | Health & Personal Development| H1*;H2*;P1;P2;P3*;OH*| NULL
      |                              |                      |
      |                              | M1;M2*; M2*;M3*      |
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   97 | Health                       | H1*;H2*              | 96
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   98 | Personal Development         | P1;P2;P3*            | 96
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   99 | Other Health                 | OH*                  | 96
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   100| Medicine                     | M1;M2*               | 97
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   101| Other Medicine               | M2*;M3*              | 97
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   102| Other Medicine 2             | NULL                 | 97
   ---|------------------------------|----------------------|---------
   ```

There are other Parent/Child corruptions in the table as well. How do I:

1. Script this to down the table in question and concatentate the
   parent records `ExternalCategoryCode` with child
   `ExternalCategoryCode` data?
2. List the Parent records which are updated. Usually when using `UPDATED`, this just shows something like this, whereby I would like to report this:

   (1 row(s) affected)

Techology Im using:

- **SQL Server**

Comment: How deep is the descendant level? For example, 97 is the child of 96. But then will there be a 101 which is the child of 97? Additionally, will there be case of two children have the same code (H1 for example), then, will the code in the parent need to be reduce this duplicate?

Comment: @DVT I will edit the question with those answers.

Comment: Edits to post added.

Comment: So you only want update the top most parent, and none in the intermediate level?

Comment: Thats right - We use the top most parent as a "catch-all" for grouping purposes. For whatever reason, I'm finding that some of our parents dont have all of its childrens (and their childrens, etc) codes.

Comment: Now is a total different question :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - sincere apologies, DVT made some valid points I didnt think of when investigating the data and writing this question.

Comment: Now you need a recursive query. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QAN56368)**
First concatenate all code from same parent, and then update.

```
WITH superParent as (
    SELECT [Id], [Id] as [topParent], [Name], [ExternalCategoryCode], [ParentId]
    FROM Table1 t
    WHERE [ParentId] is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.[Id], sp.[topParent], t.[Name], t.[ExternalCategoryCode], t.[ParentId]    
    FROM Table1 t
    JOIN superParent sp
      ON sp.[id] = t.[ParentId]
),  
combine as (
    Select distinct ST2.[topParent], 
        (
            Select ST1.[ExternalCategoryCode] + ';' AS [text()]
            From superParent ST1
            Where ST1.[topParent] = ST2.[topParent]
            ORDER BY ST1.[Id]
            For XML PATH ('')
        ) [External]
    From superParent ST2
    WHERE ST2.[ParentId] IS NOT NULL    
)    
UPDATE T
SET T.[ExternalCategoryCode] = C.[External]
FROM Table1 T
JOIN combine C
  ON T.[Id] = c.[topParent];

SELECT *
FROM Table1;
```

**OUTPUT** using recursive cte assign the top parent to each child. Then use the XML PATH to concatenate all `CategoryCode`

[image]

Comment: The ID of your last record is 98 while in the OP it should be 99

Comment: @GuidoG Thanks, dont know how that happen if I just copy/paste :$

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: i noticed after I posted and made a quick edit. Just shows how quick you are! :)

Comment: @garfbradaz Ohh that make sense,

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the silence, im going to take a look at this tomorrow morning and report back. Thanks for all of your time looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

This one is tough. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(29), [ExternalCategoryCode] nvarchar(max), [ParentId] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Id], [Name], [ExternalCategoryCode], [ParentId])
VALUES
    (96, 'Health & Personal Development', NULL, NULL),    
    (97, 'Health', 'H1*;H2*', '96'),
    (98, 'Personal Development', 'P1;P2;P3*', '96'),
    (99, 'Other Health', 'OH*', '96'),
    (100, 'Medicine', 'M1;M2*', '97'),
    (101, 'Other Medicine', 'M2*;M3*', '97'),
    (102, 'Other Medicine 2', NULL, '97')
;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Id
        , ParentId AS Direct_Parent
        , Id AS Orig_Parent
        , ExternalCategoryCode
    FROM
        #Table1
    WHERE
        ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        t1.Id
        , t1.ParentId
        , cte.Orig_Parent
        , t1.ExternalCategoryCode
    FROM
        #Table1 t1
        JOIN cte ON t1.ParentId = cte.Id
), tmp1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Orig_Parent
        , ExternalCategoryCode
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        Id <> Orig_Parent
        AND ExternalCategoryCode IS NOT NULL
), tmp2 AS (  -- If there are too many children, this one might be needed, other wise, just use tmp1 in tmp3 below
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Orig_parent
    FROM
        tmp1
), tmp3 AS (
    SELECT
        tmp2.Orig_Parent,
        (
        SELECT CONCAT(tmp1.ExternalCategoryCode,',')
        FROM
            tmp1
        WHERE
            tmp1.Orig_parent = tmp2.Orig_Parent
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        AS New_string 
    FROM
        tmp2
)
UPDATE tab
SET ExternalCategoryCode = tmp3.New_string
FROM #Table1 tab JOIN tmp3 ON tab.Id = tmp3.Orig_Parent

SELECT *
FROM
    #Table1;


DROP TABLE #Table1;
```

Comment: Updated the code. It should run now. Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: post the rextester? btw ... `CONCAT(CONCAT('-',t1.Id),'-'))`  is equal to `CONCAT('-', t1.Id ,'-' )`

Comment: No. I copied your test code from there. I never use rextester before. Thanks for the tip about CONCAT.

Comment: Just press `Save` to get a new link.

Comment: dont know what is the use for `control_string` ?  my version doesnt use it.

Comment: It is to avoid the infinite loop. Otherwise, if there is a child of a child, then it will keep adding to the temp table. (Recursive nature).

Comment: I see like `country borders` problem.

Comment: It would help if you accidentally have a loop descendate  P1->P2->P1.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Removed that piece. It is not needed.