# How to remove duplicate records while using UNION

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

i am using  2 latitude and 2 longitude in mysql table Because of some records having multiple places so i am joining both latitude and longitude records. But while joining the records with  using of UNION, some duplicate records are created which is comes earlier. So, How to avoid the duplicate records. Can some one help me please.

**How the duplicate records are created.** 
For example one record having 2 places distance between them 500 km, But when we are using HAVING distance more than 500 km. the latitude will pull the record one time and tatitude1 will pull the record one time. so we can get two records. So, this is the problem.

```
 SELECT * , (6371 * acos(cos(radians($Latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians($Longitude)) + sin(radians($Latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
 FROM mytable
 HAVING distance < $Distance

       UNION DISTINCT

 SELECT * , (6371 * acos(cos(radians($Latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude1)) * cos(radians(longitude1) - radians($Longitude)) + sin(radians($Latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude1)))) AS distance 
       FROM mytable
 HAVING distance < $Distance
 ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: UNION by default is DISTINCT. can you provide sample data? Are you sure you get duplicated rows?

Comment: well you are `UNION` the same table, what is the point of this?

Comment: yes , which is comes by latitude then the same record comes again by latitude1

Comment: `HAVING distance` without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: show us how the duplicated records looks like? Maybe are string with special/invisible characters. Because as Dekel say UNION by default remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` keep the duplicates

Comment: i am not using GROUP BY

Comment: you are asking me to show. how to show tell me

Comment: update the question with the output you get (at least part of it) that shows the duplicated rows.

Comment: i tell you how the duplicate records are creating. for example one record having 2 places distance between them 500 km, But when we using HAVING distance more than 500 km. the latitude will pull one time  and tatitude1 will pull one time. so we can get two records. i thing you can understand.

Comment: do you have any good solution

Comment: Check the output [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997245/updating-a-parent-records-field-using-childs-record-data-same-table/40997499#40997499). Something like that so we can test what is happening

Comment: That is for sql-server, not MySQL (CTE does not exist until 8.0.x or MariaDB 10.2)

Answer (score 0):

`UNION DISTINCT` compares the entire row.  That includes `distance`.  But, if I understand your description, the two distances are likely to be different.

Plan A: Not return the distance:

```
( SELECT * FROM tbl
      WHERE (big-long-forumula) < $Distance )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM tbl
      WHERE (other formula) < $Distance )
```

Plan B:  Use `OR`:

```
SELECT *,
       (...) AS distance1,
       (...) AS distance2
    FROM tbl
    HAVING distance1 < $Distance
        OR distance2 < $Distance
```

(Neither one will be 'fast', especially if you have thousands of rows to scan.)

Comment: Thanks so much, by the plan B the duplicate id are not created. thanks, thanks, thanks so much.

Comment: Your sql gives you 2 rows; my Plan B gives you 2 distances in a single row.